# Selecting data from related arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have got two arrays

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
arr2 = [3, 221, 1, 4, 25]
```

Their values have to be related like: a->3, b-> 221 and so on.
I would like to select that pairs where diffrence between each elements in second array is less than x, for instance 5.

I am expecting result as:

```
a 3
c 1
d 4
```

I've tried to sort arr2 and compare two further elements but it has to be related

Comment: What should be taken for second array data `1,2,30,31`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no clarity on how should be operated `1, 2, 10, 11, 100` array, the below is a “pattern” answer, that could be adopted to whatever condition you have.

```
values = arr2.permutation(2).select do |a,b| 
  (a-b).abs < 5 # or whatever condition
end.flatten.uniq

arr1.zip(arr2).select do |a,b|
  values.include? b
end.to_h

#⇒ {  "a" => 3, "c" => 1, "d" => 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this:

```
hash = Hash[arr1.zip(arr2)]
vals = hash.values.sort
indexes = vals.each_cons(2).collect { |a,b| b-a }.each_with_index.map{ |a, i| i+1 if a < 5 }.compact
indexes.unshift(0).uniq! if vals[indexes.first] == 1 && (vals[1] - vals[0]) > 5
hv = indexes.map { |i| vals[i] }
hv.each { |v| p hash.key(v).to_s + " " + v.to_s}
#"c 1"
#"a 3"
#"d 4"
# => [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @mudasobwa fixed. Im making assumption that these could be any two subsequent values with difference less than 5 as its not clear in OPs question.